# How can an Awakened control a whole base without losing their powers?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

This question will need some additional information, so I hope I don't enter the TLDR state; but I think explaining the scope of the question will help with answering it.

I wanted to create a run for our group with a System-Shock atmosphere (but without a KI) while allowing both the Awakened characters, the fighter and the technomancer, to really make use of their abilities outside of combat. I'm not very experienced, so the complexity involved here might be a bad idea, but at the moment it's just a premise: An out-of-control (from the corporation's point of view) base completely under control by a mage who also controls the computers, cameras, robots etc. of the base.

I know that the rules don't allow mages with technomancer powers for obvious reasons, but here it's about the bad guy and I was thinking about the following:

In the base heart, the awaken was placed in a really advanced [MRT machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging) and connected to an EEG. This avoids anything needed to be plugged into the poor fellow which would reduce his magic powers. The only stuff entering his body are for feeding and keeping him paralyzed. The MRT/EEG monitors his brain, translating his thoughts into commands for the computers of the base while, via magnetic manipulation, feeding back information to him. (There are some experiments even today showing that you can manipulate a brain via magnetic fields, and hey, it's the future!) So the poor victim of the corporations is able to control the computers and gather information from them while not losing his magic powers.

Sadly, the way the corporation used to control him failed and now the whole base (a claustrophobic bunker underneath the surface) has gone berserk. Enter the runners. (The corporation could solve this somehow, but they built the thing completely autarc, and the local commander doesn't want them to know he ruined it (it was costly!) so he prefers to hire runners over informing the board. Hence, runners.)

So:

1. Is this — in a Shadowrun sense — reasonable?
2. Is there a way to amplify the poor fellow's magic powers as well so that he might use magic throughout the whole base?

Comment: I'm away from my books at the moment, so I can't confirm that this has truly carried over into sr5, but I believe there is an item called Mage Sight goggles that allows you to cast spells around corners. Fill your walls with fiber-optic cables attached to these goggles, and you can cast everywhere that you have vision through the cables. Granted, this method of casting is easily defeated with a few cans of spray-paint...

Comment: if the cameras *are* his new natural sight, rather than being considered an augmentation, then he should be able to cast anywhere he can see through them.  Or you can go the boring route and cover the place in fiber-optic cables, yeah.  That said, there are hints in a few SR5 books that there is at least one mage-technomancer hybrid in existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I'd say yes, it is. Experimenting with human subjects, very shadowrun-ish. All that only for more power, dito. Those responsible trying to erase/cover their errors, perfect fit.
2. I know of nothing that would amplify magic in a way that circumvents the need for a mystical link (that is, you need to see or touch the subject of a spell with your natural senses or senses you bought with essence, see SR5 Core p281).

Fiber-optic cable would be feasible as Mickle suggests (see SR5 Core p444, Mage Sight Googles). Also drones could be used to carry fiber-optic cable around, either to areas not already covered by cable installed in the walls or to areas that had their fiber-optic cable coverage sabotaged. Those cables should probably have some kind of one-way mirror inbuilt, otherwise your player's mage could target the bad guy through the cable as well.

Spirits could extend the bad guy's reach as well, but I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for.

3. About the MRT: as far as I know, a decker does not need any kind of cyberware.
   Trodes provide a DNI (Direct Neural Interface) and SR5 Core p227 says about cyberdecks:

> it also has a built-in sim module, so all you need is a DNI to use it for VR right out of the box

4. As I said, I know of no way around the need for a mystic link, but there are plenty of ways a corporation could boost a mage.

   - Initiation (in your bad guy's case, with gruesome restrictions like never moving, never feeling the sun, ... if you think you can use those to further the story)
   - Foci
   - Large amount of available reagents
   - Previously bound spirits.

Comment: Thank you very much! Still a lot of work to do, but I see a path.